# Referencing variables in Firestore Rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

**Firestore Rules example**:

```
match /cities/{city} {
  allow read: if <condition>;
  allow write: if <condition>;
}
```

**Documentation page says**:

> The match statement uses the {city} wildcard syntax. This means the rule applies to any document in the cities collection, such as /cities/SF or /cities/NYC. When the allow expressions in the match statement are evaluated, **the city variable will resolve to the city document name**, such as SF or NYC.

**Question**:

How to reference that **{city}** value in actual rules and what is the syntax?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no special syntax - just use `city` as you would any other variable.  It doesn't require any namespacing or identification like `$` in some languages.

```
allow get: if city == "NYC";
```

Although the above is a silly rule, it's syntactically correct and will prevent any document other than NYC from working with a get() on the client.